# "name" property not working in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

I have a problem. I have used `name` property in the name attribute. It's not working. If I use any other property in the name attribute, then it's working. 
Thanks!

```
<form id="target" method="GET" class="map_search_form" action="https://demo.com/county/">
    <input type="hidden"  name="name">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the issue, can you explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has some words reserved for query vars. You can check them [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars).

Unless you want to mess up with the main query or the WP core, I suggest you to use a different name for your query vars / `$_GET` parameters that is not included in that list